# Unknown user seen when listing tar file

Tags: osx, users, tar

I have here a POSIX tar archive call `Debian9.ova`.

Interestingly enough, listing it with `tar` in MacOS High Sierra, shows:

```
$ tar -tvf Debian9.ova 
-rw-r--r--  0 someone someone  5344 26 Feb 13:57 Debian9.ovf
-rw-r--r--  0 someone someone   179 26 Feb 13:57 Debian9.mf
-rw-r--r--  0 someone someone 2113245184 26 Feb 13:59 Debian9-disk1.vmdk
```

Now the interesting point is, that I do not have a `someone` user and group.

```
$ id someone
id: someone: no such user
```

Listing it with `--numeric-owner`, it shows as `uid` 64, and `gid` 64, which clearly are not present in my system.

```
$ tar -tvf Debian9.ova --numeric-owner
-rw-r--r--  0 64     64       5344 26 Feb 13:57 Debian9.ovf
-rw-r--r--  0 64     64        179 26 Feb 13:57 Debian9.mf
-rw-r--r--  0 64     64 2113245184 26 Feb 13:59 Debian9-disk1.vmdk
```

Listing the users in the system does not find a `somebody` user:

```
dscl . list  /Users | grep someone
```

Where is then `someone` coming from? Is it a `tar` "feature" when it finds an unknown `uid` and `gid`?

PS. In debian just for comparison:

```
$ tar -tvf a.tar
-rw-r--r-- 64/64          3212 2018-02-27 02:01 dead.letter
$ bsdtar -tvf a.tar
-rw-r--r--  0 64     64       3212 Feb 27 02:01 dead.letter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have here a POSIX `tar` archive […]

In a standard format `tar` archive, the header information for each file contains fields for *both* a symbolic user and group name *and* a numeric user and group ID.

As you have seen, `tar` can list either one set of fields or the other.

With a conformant `pax` utility one should be able to list these fields altogether:

```
$ pax -o listopt="%(uid)s %(gid)s %(uname)s %(gname)s %L\n" < Debian9.ova
```

However, I believe that no standard-conformant `pax` utility currently exists.

## Further reading

- "[ustar header block](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html#tagtcjh_28)". `pax`.  *Single Unix Specification*.  IEEE 1003.1-2008:2016.
- Tim Kientzle (2016-12-27).  [`tar`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=5).  § 5.  *FreeBSD File Formats Manual*.

Comment: A conforming pax implementation dumps core with your proposed command line. Use listopt="%(uid)d %(gid)d %(uname)s %(gname)s %L\n" on Solaris, AIX, HP-UX and it will work.